# Why is H₂O V shaped?

Tags: water, bond

We know that the molecule of H₂O is V-shaped. This is what makes it a dipole.

[image]

But why is that? I mean, if the hydrogens have a partial positive charge, then they should try to get away from each other, until they are diametrically opposite to the oxygen molecule. But that doesn't happen. Why is this?

Comment: If you're interested at why molecules have a given shape, read up on [VSEPR theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSEPR_theory) (Valence shell electron pair repulsion), which is the typical undergraduate-level model for understanding/explaining these things.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The oxygen atom fills its octet rule by forming two bonds. It shares 1 electron in a covalent bond with each hydrogen and has 4 remaining valence electrons. It is  [sp$^3$ hybridized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_hybridisation#sp3_hybrids) and has the 4 non-bonding electrons in two lone pairs. An sp$^3$ hybridized atom has four attachment points spaced approximately 109$^\circ$ apart and has the shape of a pyramid with a triangular base. See [this image](http://image.tutorvista.com/cms/images/44/bond-angles-in-water.JPG) for an example. You don't typically see the water molecule drawn in 3 dimensional space with the lone pairs of electrons, all you see is a planar molecule with H-O-H bond angle of ~109$^\circ$.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the + charges on hydrogens, but the negative charges on the O-H bonds, and on the O it self that is dominant in determining the molecule's shape. There are four non-bonding electrons on O -two lone pairs- on top of the two O-H bonds.

So you should think of four groups around O, not two.

Answer (score 3):

> I mean, if the hydrogens have a partial positive charge, then they should try to get away from each other.

Well, this is not a complete answer to your question, but this could be a factor I guess.

Bond pair – lone pair repulsion is always greater than bond pair – bond pair repulsion

So what I want to say is that **the repulsion between the O---H bond and the lone pair** is so heavy such that it is really hard for two hydrogen atoms to get away each other as you are expecting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

In the bonding of Oxygen with Hydrogen, Oxygen ends up with 2 extra electrons, giving it what is called the "bent" shape. This is because the attachments and the electrons all repel each other but the electrons are not drawn except in a Lewis Dot structure such as the one here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Water-2D-flat.png

Comment: Oxygen has four extra electrons: two lone pairs.